# Disparity map for objects very close to cameras in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to compute a disparity map between stereo images of eye retina, i.e. the back of the eye, where the depths, proportional to the disparities, are in the range of mm.

I tried using OpenCV's StereoBM and StereoSGBM but the result, even with the tuning of numDisparities and blockSize, is low-quality, full of noise and sometimes also inconsistent.
The problem may be the range of depths that is really low.

Do stereoSGBM and stereoBM have known problems and limitations when objects are extremely close to the cameras and the depth delta is in the range of few millimetres? Or, do I need just to properly tune params and do some appropriate pre-processing?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Basically, my question is: do stereoSGBM and stereoBM have problems and limitations when objects are extremely close to the cameras and the depth delta is in the range of few millimetres? Or, do I need just to properly tune params and do some appropriate pre-processing? Sorry for not have been clear.

Comment: Please, edit your question instead of answering in the comments.